# Flask / Werkzeug request objects form parameter

Tags: python, flask, python-requests, werkzeug

I have an Flask app that serves an API to a Django consumer. I use the [requests library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) in my consumer to hit the API.

My problem is this: When I test my API I get POST data in `request.form`, and when I hit it from my consumer (using requests library) I get POST data in `request.data`.

E.g.,

API endpoint in Flask app:

```
@mod.route('/customers/', methods=['POST'])
def create_prospect():
    customer = Customer()
    prospect = customer.create_prospect(request.form)
    return jsonify(prospect.serialize()), 201
```

Testing API endpoint in Flask app:

```
def test_creating_prospect(self):
    with self.app.app_context():
        data = {'name': 'Test company and co'}
        response = self.client.post(self.url, data=data)
        ...
```

This populates `request.form` in my endpoint, which works fine.

Consuming the API from my Django app, using requests:

```
...
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}
data = {'name': 'Test company and co'}
response = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
```

This populates `request.data` in my endpoint, which fails as I'm checking `request.form` for the info.

I've had a thought while writing this question; Maybe the json headers are making `request.data` be populated instead of `request.form`?

Any input appreciated.

**Edit - I tried adding the headers to my test, worked fine:**

```
    headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}
    response = self.client.post(self.url, data=data, headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ah, I was sending an incorrect Content-Type.  Changing it to 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' makes `request.form` get the right stuff.

`request.data` is populated with stuff Flask/Werkzeug doesn't know what to do with [according to the docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Request.data).